# Criar uma nova função com scrapy

Tags: python, python-3.x, scrapy

Estou começando a aprender scrapy e criei a seguinte função:

```
import scrapy


class ModelSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = "model"
    start_urls = [
        'http://www.icarros.com/'
    ]

def parse(self, response):
    with open('brands.csv', 'r') as all_brands:
        for brand in all_brands:
            brand = brand.replace("\n", "")
            url = 'http://www.icarros.com/'+brand
            yield scrapy.Request(url, self.success_connect)

def success_connect(self, response):
    self.log('Entrei')
```

Mas aparece o seguinte erro:

```
AttributeError: 'ModelSpider' object has no attribute 'success_connect'
```

Comment: Pode postar o contexto do código? Ele deveria estar numa classe

Comment: está em um spider. @rodorgas

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Tem um problema na indentação do seu arquivo. As duas funções estão fora da classe (como Python não tem `{ }`, é a indentação que define os blocos de código). O arquivo `carros_spider.py` funcionando fica assim:

```
import scrapy


class ModelSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = "model"
    start_urls = [
        'http://www.icarros.com/'
    ]

    def parse(self, response):
        for brand in ['ford', 'toyota']:
            brand = brand.replace("\n", "")
            url = 'http://www.icarros.com/'+brand
            yield scrapy.Request(url, self.success_connect)

    def success_connect(self, response):
        self.log('Entrei')
```

Para executar:

```
scrapy runspider carros_spider.py
```

[Veja o output](https://gist.github.com/rodorgas/811528987eeeb2797240aaa1628db7e0) desse comando.